# Поиск максимальной суммы чисел

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, оптимизация

**Условие:** Есть массив целых чисел N и есть число P. **Вопрос:** как найти индексы элементов N такие, чтобы сумма ΣN(i) была максимально приближена к P.

**Например,** N = [2, 5, 8] и P = 11. Правильный ответ будет 10 = 8 + 2.

Каким способом кроме перебора можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Граничные условия надо добавить если P больше суммы всех элементов или меньше минимального элемента массива задача превращается в фарс.

Comment: С ходу могу предложить очень медленное костыльное решение. Берете этот код http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/
Применяете его к каждой перестановке исходного массива. Если он ничего не находит уменьшаете входное число P на единицу и снова повторяете до тех пор пока не найдете нужный массив.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, ваша задача совсем немного отличается от [knapsack problem](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5).

Comment: igumnov, вы правы, граничные условия и правда не помешают! Спасибо за предложенное решение, но P в моём случае достаточно большое число, порядка десятков тысяч, и уменьшать на единицу каждый раз будет горячкой.
VlaD, и правда, разберу статью, спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частный случай задачи об укладке рюкзака (вес и ценность предметов одинакова) [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5).

Comment: Да, это действительно оказалась укладка рюкзака :)
@VladD @igumnov спасибо вам за ценные советы, они мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная задача на динамическое программирование